# How to Query Using WHERE and AND without Combining Multiple Fields

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I'm working on a table in visual studio that is querying a SQL database. I have parameters for the user to select a date within a start and end date or to be able to type a server name instead.

What I also want to happen is if the user wants to select a date AND a server name I only want the table to return the date with that specific server name but what is happening is it is returning all rows with the selected date and all rows with the typed server name. I have 2 rows with the same server name but one has a date of 06/06 and the other has a date of 06/07. If I choose the date 06/07 and the server name: SQL1, I only want the table to return that one row of the server: SQL1 with the date: 06/07.

```
SELECT        ServerName, ServiceName, Status, Date
FROM          ServicesStatus
WHERE         (Date = @Date) AND (@Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR
              (ServerName = @ServerName) OR
              (Date = @Date) AND (@Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (ServerName = @ServerName)
```

This is what the first WHERE statement looks like when I select 06/07/18 as the date:

```
ServerName:    ServiceName:         Date:
SQL3           Service1             06/07/18
SQL4           Service2             06/07/18
SQL2           Service1             06/07/18
SQL1           Service1             06/07/18
```

This is what the second WHERE statement after the first OR looks like when I select SQL1 as my ServerName:

```
ServerName:    ServiceName:         Date:
SQL1           Service1             06/07/18
SQL1           Service2             06/06/18
```

And **HERE'S MY PROBLEM!** It looks like this when I'm trying to do the third WHERE Statement after the second OR because it combines the date I selected (06/07/18) with the server name I typed which is SQL1:

```
ServerName:    ServiceName:         Date:
SQL3           Service1             06/07/18
SQL4           Service2             06/07/18
SQL2           Service1             06/07/18
SQL1           Service1             06/07/18
SQL1           Service2             06/06/18
```

I want it like this after I select the above data (SQL1 and 06/07/18) if they choose to filter it by server name and date:

```
ServerName:    ServiceName:         Date:
SQL1           Service1             06/07/18
```

I know it's a simple query but I just can't figure it out for some reason.

Comment: What is the default value of the @ Date and @ ServerName parameters? Within your first two statements you need to essentially check that only a single parameter was included, otherwise make those clauses false and rely on the final one.

Comment: In other words, something like the following pseudo-sql:  WHERE (@ Date is provided AND @ Date is in range AND @Servername is not provided) OR (@ Servername is provided AND @ Date is not) OR (both are provided)

Comment: So you could basically check against a default value or more preferably a NULL value (if the parameters are passed in as NULL when not provided).

Comment: the default for @ Date is the current date (=Today()) and there is no default value for @ ServerName since if they view the table the first records they will see will be from the current date. And then if they want they can make the date NULL and then search for a specific server name. What I'm wanting is for them to be able search both and return the record(s) that contain the Server name they typed and the date they chose without combining all instances of the selected date. @CaitLAN Jenner

Comment: you could technically use a case statement to see which parameters were provided, then use the appropriate WHERE clause for your specific case.

Comment: I have updated the answer to using dynamically prepared statements. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a dynamic SQL query or prepare statement! We can create optimizing filtering logic on the fly by combining both of them. You can also modify to introduce a stored procedure along the same lines.

**Dynamic Prepare Statement:** Creates a prepared version of the command on an instance of SQL Server with dynamic filtering.

1. Prepared Statement doesn't introduce SQL Injection
2. The improved solution with Below logic to dynamically add parameters and filter string. (With all the parameters in `WHERE` clause leads to Table Scan because the execution engine prepares for the worst)

The following example demonstrates the use of the Prepare method.

```
private static void SqlCommandPrepareEx(string connectionString)
{
    var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    var filterSb = new StringBuilder();

    PopulateParameters(sqlParameters, filterSb);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);

        // Create and prepare an SQL statement.
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ServerName, ServiceName, Status, Date" + "FROM ServicesStatus" + filterSb;

        // Adding Parameters
        command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters.ToArray());
        // Call Prepare after setting the Command text and Parameters.
        command.Prepare();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

private static void PopulateParameters(List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters, StringBuilder filterSb)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputDate))
    {
        // Add Parameter
        var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = InputDate };
        sqlParameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        // Add Filter
        filterSb.AppendLine(filterSb.Length > 0 ? " AND Date=@date" : " WHERE Date=@date");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StartDate))
    {
        // Add Parameter
        var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@startDate", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = StartDate };
        sqlParameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        // Add Filter
        // Using Between affects performance and don't allow indexes to be used
        filterSb.AppendLine(filterSb.Length > 0 ? " AND Date>=@startDate" : " WHERE Date>=@startDate");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EndDate))
    {
        // Add Parameter
        var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@endDate", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = EndDate };
        sqlParameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        // Add Filter
        // Using Between affects performance and don't allow indexes to be used
        filterSb.AppendLine(filterSb.Length > 0 ? " AND Date<=@endDate" : " WHERE Date<=@endDate");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerName))
    {
        // Add Parameter
        var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@serverName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = ServerName };
        sqlParameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        // Add Filter
        filterSb.AppendLine(filterSb.Length > 0 ? " AND ServerName=@serverName" : " WHERE ServerName=@serverName");
    }
}
```

**Understanding Dynamic Queries Alone:**
The following example to understand dynamic queries, it can be made safer by introducing it in the stored procedure with appropriate logic.

```
var filterString = string.Empty;
string dynamicQuery = @"
SELECT        ServerName, ServiceName, Status, Date
FROM          ServicesStatus
{0}";

//Populate Filter String
var filterSb = new StringBuilder();

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateFilter)){
    filterSb.AppendLine("Date = {0}", dateFilter)
}

// use similar code for other filters

if(filterSb.Length > 0){
    filterString = string.Format(" WHERE {0}", filterSb);
}

// Append filter
string.Format(dynamicQuery, filterString);
```

**Understanding Prepared Statements alone:**
Creates a prepared version of the command on an instance of SQL Server.

```
private static void SqlCommandPrepareEx(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);

        // Create and prepare an SQL statement.
        command.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) " +
            "VALUES (@id, @desc)";
        SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 0);
        SqlParameter descParam = 
            new SqlParameter("@desc", SqlDbType.Text, 100);
        idParam.Value = 20;
        descParam.Value = "First Region";
        command.Parameters.Add(idParam);
        command.Parameters.Add(descParam);

        // Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
        command.Prepare();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Change parameter values and call ExecuteNonQuery.
        command.Parameters[0].Value = 21;
        command.Parameters[1].Value = "Second Region";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP was using the context of a stored procedure. This may work, but it isn't a prepared statement and could be vulnerable to a SQL injection if the inputs are not properly sanitized.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner I agree to it. I will update my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

If the values of @Date and @ServerName are NULL when not provided then the following should work for you. I created a sample table and populated it with the data you provided. This should produce the results you are looking for. You can adjust the DATEDIFF for precision if needed. I also assumed start date and end date would be different intervals of the same day since it was not specified. Feel free to modify as needed.

```
CREATE TABLE ServicesStatus (
id INT,
serverName VARCHAR(255),
ServiceName VARCHAR(255),
Date DATETIME2
);


DECLARE @Date DATETIME2 = '06/07/18'
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2 = dateadd(second, 1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @Date), 0))
    , @EndDate DATETIME2 = dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @Date)+1, 0))
    , @ServerName VARCHAR(255) = NULL

SELECT    ServerName, ServiceName, Date
FROM      ServicesStatus
WHERE     ServerName = COALESCE(@ServerName,ServerName)
AND       (@Date IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,Date) >= 0)
AND       (@Date IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY,Date,@EndDate) <= 0)
```

Comment: It gives me an error: Eror in WHERE clause near'='. Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Edited and tested within a local environment to produce the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.  If you are not setting the unknown values to NULL, replace NULL with whatever value you are using in your variables for "don't care".

You didn't give values for @StartDate and @EndDate, so I assume they are just acting as outer filters.

```
--The Setup
DECLARE @ServicesStatus TABLE ([ServerName] varchar(4), [ServiceName] varchar(8), [Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO @ServicesStatus
    ([ServerName], [ServiceName], [Date])
VALUES
    ('SQL3', 'Service1', '2018-06-07 00:00:00'),
    ('SQL4', 'Service2', '2018-06-07 00:00:00'),
    ('SQL2', 'Service1', '2018-06-07 00:00:00'),
    ('SQL1', 'Service1', '2018-06-07 00:00:00'),
    ('SQL1', 'Service2', '2018-06-06 00:00:00')
;

DECLARE @StartDate date = '20180601'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '20180610'
DECLARE @Date date = '20180607'
DECLARE @ServerName nvarchar(4)='SQL1'

--The Code
SELECT        ServerName, ServiceName, Date
FROM          @ServicesStatus
WHERE         (@Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate OR @DATE IS NULL) AND
              (
                (ServerName = @ServerName AND @Date IS NULL) OR
                (@ServerName IS NULL AND @Date = date) OR
                (Date= @Date AND ServerName = @ServerName)
               )
```

With @Servername = NULL and @Date = '20180607', you get

```
ServerName  ServiceName Date
SQL3    Service1    2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
SQL4    Service2    2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
SQL2    Service1    2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
SQL1    Service1    2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
```

With @Date = NULL and @ServerName = 'SQL1' you get

```
ServerName  ServiceName Date
SQL1    Service1    2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
SQL1    Service2    2018-06-06 00:00:00.000
```

And with @Date = '20180607' and @ServerName = 'SQL1', you get

```
ServerName  ServiceName Date
SQL1    Service1    2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
```